# how to make my Linux to listen on his public ip rather than the private IP

Tags: linux, centos, port, nat, cloud

I have a virtual machine on some public cloud.
the physical IP  is not routeble. 
the ISP provided for me with a public IP and  the NAT is being done using the ISP FW.

on that Server I'm running WowzaServer that is running on port TCP 1935 and TCP 80.

when I log in to that server and try to telnet to the public IP on these ports I get connection refused. when I do the same to the physical IP it's working.
(it's also working to the public IP when I try to telnet from a remote computer other than the local computer).
My ISP says he can't do anything to solve it - I also have the same server on Amazon VPC and it works great!!
is there a work around to make my server to listen to my public IP as well?
THnaks!
Dotan.

Comment: Do you understand how NAT really works? Because here I don't see anything wrong (ie "working as designed(tm)").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are trying to talk to your own public IP address from behind the NAT I think you need a NAT hairpin. The owner of the router dong the NAT would have to configure this for you but not all routers are capable of this. If your ISP cannot or won't supply you with a hairpin then there isn't very much you can do.